# How to disable local switching in linux

Tags: linux, networking

I am running a server on one interface and a client on another.  For certain reasons, I need to make sure all the traffic egresses from the box and isn't locally switched inside the Linux networking stack.  Is there a way to force the Linux networking stack to always send packets out the wire even when the destination MAC matches another interface on the same machine?

Comment: are both interfaces on the same lan segment? Standard IP routing rules are going to apply in most cases.   But just clarifying you have  interfaces on the box,  192.168.10.2 and 192.168.10.3, and you want .2 to talk to .3 via the ethernet and not locally? If so curious as to why?

Comment: I'm actually running a DHCPv6 server/client with a relay agent between them.  The packets need to egress in order to go through the relay agent.  So the client doesn't actually have an IPv6 address during the first part of this transaction.  That's why I assumed it was locally switching at the MAC layer.

Answer (score 0):

Is IP forwarding enabled? If so then try disabling it and it will stop the kernel routing between the internal interfaces.

for IPV4 this would be

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=0
```

It's not something I've ever tried but I guess the ipv6 equivalent would be

```
sysctl -w net.ipv6.ip_forward=0
```